# Where should I put the breakpoint that VS debugger will activate when I enter something in Python interpreter?

Tags: visual-studio, cpython

I'm trying to learn about how the Python interpreter works via
debugging it in interactive mode.

I've managed to compile [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) with Visual Studio 2019 on windows 10, using the `PCbuild\pcbuild.sln` solution.

I tried debug from `python.c` as the file is the only one in "Source Files" panel.

[image]

and then I tracked it to `main.c`

[image]

[image]

I tried to put breakpoints there, pressed F5, VS activated the breakpoints during launching the interpreter.

However, when I entered something in the interpreter being debugged, VS didn't activate any breakpoint.

[image]

Where should I put the breakpoint that VS debugger will activate when I enter something in Python interpreter?

PS:

I also tried put another line there

[image]

and got same situation, that is, debugger hits the breakpoint only once when VS launches the console. After that, debugger never hits the breakpoint again.

[image]

[image]

## pymain_init

[image]

## stop the program

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: press F5 , it should open a command window for you

Comment: what if you put your breakpoint in the very beginning? (in wmain() method). If it stops there, you can continue with it using F11 to step into each method...

Comment: Await Python prompts for a command, and stop the program in the debugger.  Locate the thread awaiting the user input and walk back the stack until you find the Read–eval–print loop.

Comment: @SeReGa I'm not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly. I just updated my OP, that is, the `pymain_init` part, which shows that the first method in `cpython\Modules\main.c` is `pymain_init(.)`

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you. I'm not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly. I just updated my OP, that is, the `stop the program` part, where I stopped the program but I didn't see anything that looked like  thread stack.

Comment: If your goal is to become a Python core developer, the right guide is https://devguide.python.org not blindly try and guess in VS.

Comment: @JJJohn I would suggest that you get a little more familiar with the debugger on a project with code you wrote yourself before trying this.  Knowing your tools is important.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start by making sure that the code path you are expecting is actually being called. For example, add something like this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "This is interesting...!\n");
```

Add a breakpoint to the same line.  Build and run.  If the message appears, but the debugger doesn't stop execution then you've hit a not uncommon bug that breakpoints stop working.  Double check your solution/project settings and make sure everything looks right and you are doing a debug build.  If that all looks ok then try "VS > Tools > Import and Export Settings… > Reset all settings."

Anyway, back to Python!  This site has some great "internal" to give you an idea of where to start: https://realpython.com/cpython-source-code-guide/#reading-filesinput

I would look at Modules/main.c and breakpoint all the pymain_run_* functions.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I understand your suggestion correctly. I updated my OP. Would you please take a loot at it?

Comment: I'm learning the tutorial you recommend and I'll let you know if it answers my question. Thank you!